# Ubuntu crashes on startup with a call trace (release_bts_buffer)

Tags: ubuntu, crash, buffer

A friend of mine is having problems with her Ubuntu laptop and I have trouble finding informations that could help me know what is going on.
I think this is a bit beyond the scope of my abilities.

The only info I have is this screenshot :

[image: Call trace on startup]

This apparently didn't happen after an update or software installation.
I'm not trying to search for the root cause at all costs, a complete reinstallation is completely an option, just wondered if maybe someone here encountered something similar and might have an idea what could be causing it before we reset everything!

Thank you for your time

Comment: From the picture posted, the error could be anything.

Comment: Anything as in, anything from hardware to software? What would be additionnal troubleshooting steps I could take to know more about an error like this?